# Script with condition

Tags: bash, shell

I am a beginner in the development of scripts.I want to do 4 tasks in one script: 
1. Connect to machine 1 by ssh 
2.Retrieve the data and put it in a CSV file
3.Send the CSV file to a directory
4.connect to machine 2 by ssh and do step 2 and 3

Fisrt test :

```
#!/bin/bash
#Settings
DATE=$(date +%Y_%m_%d)
DATE1=$(date +%d/%m/%Y)
HIER=$(date  -d '1 day ago' "+%Y-%m-%d")
HEURE=$(date +"%T")
#Ip adress of the machine
machine1= IP1 
machine2= IP2

#Connexion SSH OLT1 
ssh root@IP1

#Command for geting data on machine
enable
config
display XXXX > IP1.csv

#exit connection
exit
```

I do not have any result so i think 
Do i make a loop for executing the task for the 2 machines?

Thanks

I'm trying tu use expect because i find RSA key problem by using SSH and shell script

```
#spawn ssh $host -l $user
expect "login:"
send "root\r"

expect  "passe:"
send "test\r"

expect -re $prompt
send "terminal length 0\r"

expect -re $prompt
send "enable\r"

expect -re $prompt
send "config\r"

expect -re $prompt
send "display .....\r"

expect -re "\r\nend\r\n"
send "exit\r"
```

I don't know how i can put the result on csv file to a directory?
Besides, can i put the IP on #spawn assume that task should be done on 2 machines

Thanks for your feedback

I try thisaccording to your sample but the ouput file is empty: 
    #!/usr/bin/expect

```
spawn ssh X.X.X.X -l root

expect "User password:"
send "admin\n"
expect -re "device>"
send "enable\r"
expect -re "device#"
 send "config\r"

expect -re "device(config)#"
send "display .......\r"
expect -re "{ <cr>||<K> }:"
send "\r"
set date [timestamp -format %C%y%m%d]
log_file -noappend /home/device/CSTtest.csv
```

Comment: There's a larger problem here. `enable` won't run until after `ssh` has exited. As this is written, it's something that runs *after* `ssh`, not something *sent to* `ssh`.

Comment: btw, `machine1= IP1` runs a command called `IP1` with the environment variable `machine1` set to an empty value; it's *not* an assignment, due to the space. This is an issue that http://shellcheck.net/ would identify for you automatically.

Comment: Googling `site:stackoverflow.com script cisco ios bash ssh` might be your best place to get started here.

Comment: The better way is to use tools such as ansible/salt/fab to do your job, just set the public key on all machines. ssh ENV is interactive, not so good for your case.

Answer (score 1):

You can run your command and export to out file in same ssh call like this:

```
# ...
# first machine command
ssh root@IP1 "<COMMAND>" > /PATH_LOCAL_TO_SAVE_FILE/IP1.csv

# second machine command
ssh root@IP2 "<COMMAND>" > /PATH_LOCAL_TO_SAVE_FILE/IP2.csv
```

Comment: thanks @Igor Uchôa but the file is empty..the "display command" is not executing.

Comment: what you want to do with display command? If it is the same display used to show images in linux, make sure that you have display command installed or active in you remote machine. If you is only trying to retrieve text data, you can use a text viewer ("less" command, for example).

Comment: ,yes "display command is activated and working" in remote machine.I try to connect to the machine, read dat an save the result in a file.And finally with crontrab,run the script one time per day